# How to handle this json response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am having trouble figuring out how to handle a json response.  I just need to take all of the html part and put it into a div.  So I can see in console the request is successful and returns something like :

```
{"goto_section":"review","update_section":{"name":"review","html":" <div> A bunch of html</div>"}}
```

How do I take this response and put it into my div?

```
$('my-div').html(response);
```

Thanks for any help and if you know any good resources where I could learn more I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('my-div').html(response.update_section.html);
```

Also make sure that if you are using `$.post` or `$.get`, set the parameter after the callback to be `json`, or if you are using `$.ajax`, set `dataType:json`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
var html = response.update_section.html;
// or using brackets: response["update_section"]["html"];

$('my-div').html(html);
```

JSON is a JavaScript object. Here is the good reference to read about working with JavaScript objects:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0):

First, use "JSON" as the data type in your jQuery request, and in your success callback:

```
$(...).html(data.update_section.html);
```